# Логгирование в fastapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

Как перегрузить стандартные логи фастапи? Стандартный мой лог выглядит так:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53622 - "GET /api-key?access_token=1234567890qwertyuiop HTTP/1.1" 307 Temporary Redirect
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53622 - "GET /docs HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53622 - "GET /openapi.json HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53622 - "GET /docs HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53622 - "GET /openapi.json HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

А я бы хотел, чтобы там было как минимум тело запроса ещё. Можно воспользоваться `logger`. Но там максимум что я смогу сделать -- это добавить дату.

Comment: Не уверен, что вывести тело запроса вообще технически возможно. Оно ведь не хранится в памяти целиком и вообще может быть потенциально бесконечным

Answer (score 0):

В отличие от uvicorn, под которым обычно запускается fastapi, в fastapi можно очень легко поменять формат вывода. Делает это удалением логгера fastapi и созданием нового, кастомного. На этот счёт существует [две](https://medium.com/1mgofficial/how-to-override-uvicorn-logger-in-fastapi-using-loguru-124133cdcd4e) [ссылки](https://gist.github.com/Slyfoxy/a3e31cfcc1b19cba8e1b626276148c49).

```
def make_logger(rotation_size, level):
    logger.remove()
    pid = os.getpid()
    dt = datetime.datetime.now()
    logger.add(
        f'data/logs/fastapi-{dt}-{pid}.log',
        rotation=rotation_size,
        enqueue=True,
        backtrace=True,
        level=level,
        format="{time} %s {level} {message}" % pid,
    )
    return logger.bind()
```